# Big O Analysis with sub loop of varying size

Tags: c#, big-o

I've been doing some practice problems for some interviews coming up, and I was curious about something. Say, for example, in the following algorithm

```
foreach(User friend in friends) 
{
    foreach(Purchase purchase in friend.Purchases)
    {
        allFriendsPurchases.Add(purchase);
    }
}
```

So, going through each friend is O(n), because we're iterating through all the friends. But what about the sub loop? There are some friends that may not have purchased anything, and some that have purchased a lot. How would you describe the run time in Big O Notation?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say O(n*m), where n is the size of friends and m is the size of the largest purchase collection.

Comment: That looks pretty O(n2). A loop is generally considered O(n), nested loops are O(n2), O(n3), .. and so on (polynomial behavior). Also, you should factor in stuff like 'best', 'average', 'worst' case since those make a difference as well.

Comment: @sircodesalot: The number of purchases per friend is not based on the number of friends.  `O(n^2)` would be like looping through `friends` a second time to count how many friend-pairs shared a purchase or something like that.

Comment: @sircodesalot It's code like this that clearly demonstrates why that logic is flawed.  This code inherently *isn't* O(n^2) despite having nested loops.  (The reason of course is that iterations of the two loops aren't based on the same variable.)

Comment: @Servy that's exactly what was confusing me. I always hear that nested loops are O(n^2), but in this case it just didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those cases where it's important to specify what `n` is.  This algorithm can be defined as being O(n) *where `n` represents the total number of purchases*, not the total number of friends.

If you want to define `n` as the number of friends then `n` alone isn't enough variables.  The number of iterations is dependent on more than just how many friends there are.  There are different ways in which you could describe the number of iterations; one way would be to say that this algorithm is O(n*m) where `n` is the number of friends and `m` is the average number of purchases per friend.  (If `m` were known to be small, say less than some fixed value, then you can transform that to O(n), claiming that `m` is constant, but that isn't true in the general case.)

Comment: Perfect! This makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I'll accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow let's me

Comment: Nice answer I admit but in general case (in terms of loop iteration) I would say the complexity is `O(n ^ 2)` since the inner loop will be evaluated irrespective of there is a legitimate purchase present or not. What you say?

Comment: @Rahul I would say that you are entirely incorrect.  What is `n` even represent in your assertion that this is O(n^2)?  Is `n` the number of friends?  As to your assertion, iterating a loop with zero items is an O(1) operation, not an O(n) operation.  The number of purchases present is not irrelevant, in fact it is *extremely* relevant.  The number of operations performed here is in fact directly proportional to the number of purchases (which is exactly what my first paragraph is stating).